# OSX - Toubleshooting WiFi Scanner/Printer

Tags: macos, network-printer

My Brother MFC-J410W Scanner/Printer used to work fine with my MacBook Pro for both scanning and printing.  Originally, the printer was detected automatically by OSX (Snow Leopard) with no special setup.

Recently, I am no longer able to scan, and I can print only by setting up the printer manually (using its IP address).

I'll appreciate any troubleshooting tips, specifically -  how can I tell whether the problem is in the printer, in my Macbook or in the wireless router?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've reached the tentative conclusion that the problem is with my wireless router (or with the way it's set up).

- Set up an ad-hoc wireless network using the Macbook airport
- Connected the printer to the new wireless network
- Manually set up IP addresses for both Macbook and airport to be in the same range (192.168.1.*)

Now my Macbook sees the printer and I am able to scan.

The next step will be to understand what's wrong with the router (I'll start with a factory reset ...).